# Design a circuit implementing the unitary matrix

Tags: programming

Is it possible to design a circuit implementing the unitary matrix

$$U-\begin{bmatrix}
R_{\Theta_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & R_{\Theta_2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & R_{\Theta_3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & R_{\Theta_4} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

for given four angles $\Theta_1,...,\Theta_4$ , where 0 is 2×2-dimensional zero matrix and $R_{\Theta}$ is the rotation matrix with angle $\Theta$?

If so, can we implement it on the available quantum programming platforms such as Qiskit, CirQ, PyQuil, or ProjectQ?

Comment: If you write the matrix explicitly and the matrix is unitary, then for `qiskit`, you can first `from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator`, and then `O=Operator(yourUnitaryMatrix)`

Comment: @YitianWang The matrix defined by Marija is always unitary as it made from rotation matrix. I think she is asking for a generalized parameterized circuit that this matrix can be decomposed into.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt, the form of her matrix is unitary. The instruction my earlier provided can do such things, but I do not know how IBM quantum computer really do when simulating such an operation(like how they decompose a single-qubit unitary, i.e., one qubit sets of $\hat S, \hat H, \hat T$ or $\sigma_x, \sigma_z$ blabla). Other packages is out of my familiarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At worst, you could perform the construction
[image]
but depending on your different rotations, you may be able to make some efficiency savings. For example, one improvement that you can always make is you could start by applying $R_1$ on the first qubit without controlling it off anything, and then applying $R_iR_1^\dagger$ for the other three controlled-controlled operations.

Comment: Thank you for your help.